# Render item from related list on Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, related-list, repeat

I'm trying to render an item from one related list on PDF. the structure is following:
I have Sales Order, where is lookup field to Company, on Company is related list of Bank Accounts which I need to render. The Bank Accounts are related to Company through lookup, not master-detail. Here is code which I'm  using:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!salesInvoice.c2g__OwnerCompany__r.c2g__BankAccounts__r}" var="account">  
<apex:outputText value="{!account.c2g__AccountName__c}" rendered="true" escape="false"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

But get an error:

> Error: Aggregate Relationship is used in an unsupported complex
>   expression containing 'c2g__OwnerCompany__r.c2g__bankaccounts__r'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind two levels down child relationships.

Your `apex:repeat` binding looks like this:

```
salesInvoice.c2g__OwnerCompany__r.c2g__BankAccounts__r
```

The problem is that `c2g__OwnerCompany__r` is a list. But you're trying to tell the interator to bind to a list *within* a list: `c2g__OwnerCompany__r.c2g__BankAccounts__r`.

This is not allowed.

In theory you could do something like:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!salesInvoice.c2g__OwnerCompany__r}" var="ownerCompany">  
  <apex:repeat value="{!ownerCompany.c2G__BankAccounts__r}" var="account">
    <apex:outputText value="{!account.c2g__AccountName__c}" rendered="true" escape="false"/>
  </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

This would give you the ability to list all children of children.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Tried it and the error is still the same. In the second line the c2g__BankAccounts__r should be name of the lookup relationship on a Bank Account, right?

Comment: Didn't work for me